# Active vs Newest vs Featured

Tags: discussion

I get the feeling that questions under the Newest area get a lot more love than the Active or the Featured area because in short, that's where the most points to be made are. Does anyone else get this impression?

I would like to take a vote to see how many use Newest most versus Active most.

The reason I ask this is because I feel like active questions (and featured questions) don't really get the love they deserve. What's the point of putting a bounty on a question if you're likely to get more attention on it by deleting your original question and re-asking it *(obviously bad practice and I wouldn't condone doing it)* because then you'll move to the top of the newest stack? With the vote we'd be able to see whether or not people actually use the active stack which would bump featured items to the top.

With these results, we could determine if action is needed to better serve the community. I'll make two answers and then they can just be voted on.

---

**EDIT:** Thus far, it appears that I have simply been using the SE in a poor manner for the past year or so. The majority of users thus far use the active tab the majority of the time. No change appears necessary at this time.

Comment: When I'm in the mood to build rep, I tend to go newest.  Otherwise, I usually stay on active

Comment: @ScottSeidman Great feedback, good to know.

Comment: by the way, the front page defaults to "Active" view

Comment: I feel like this is a hair splitting matter.

Comment: @Nick, I think SE uses per-site cookies to keep track of the last view you used. I just went to a site I've never visited before and newest was the default. Ahh hang on that's only the question page not the front page which is active as you said.

Comment: @PeterJ I discussed this with a moderator on another SE site and both of you are right. SE uses cookies for the **Questions** page. The main page (not the questions page) defaults to Active view.

Comment: I'm mainly active on the active questions. The new ones will pop up there as well. And reading answers from other people can be very interesting and boosted my knowledge a lot already.

Answer (score 5):

I use the "Active" Questions stack the majority of the time.

Answer (score 3):

I use the "Newest" Question stack the majority of the time.